# Программа Turtle выполняется корректно, но редактор пишет об ошибке (не понимаю их сути)

Tags: python, рисование, turtle

Начинаю кодить в Python'е и решил изучить Turtle:

```
import turtle
from turtle import *
t=Turtle()
t.reset()
t.screen.setup(1000,1000)
t.up()
t.speed(1)
t.goto(-400,0)
t.down()
def Cube():
    for i in range (3):
        t.forward(100)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward (100)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(100)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(100)
        t.up()
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(200)
        t.down()
Cube()
t.up()
t.goto(-300,100)
t.down()
Cube()
t.screen.exitonclick()
t.screen.mainloop()
```

Выполняется корректно, однако в редакторе выдается 3 ошибки, не пойму их сути, есть о чем волноваться?

1. Undefined variable 'Turtle' pylint(undefined-variable)[3, 3]
2. Function already defined line 2 pylint(function-redefined) [10, 1]
3. Unused variable 'i'pylint(unused-variable) [11-9]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы два раза импортируете один и тот же модуль разными способами:

```
import turtle
from turtle import *
```

Думаю, ни к чему хорошему это не приведёт. Дело в том, что если оставить только первый оператор, то надо писать так:

```
t=turtle.Turtle()
```

А если оставить только вторую строчку, то надо писать так, как Вы написали:

```
t=Turtle()
```

но тогда есть шанс конфликта имён. Рекомендую выбрать что-то одно.

Для проверки я выбрал первый вариант и Ваша программа нарисовала вполне адекватные "шашечки для такси".

Answer (score 0):

Кратко об этом:

1. По всей видимости pylint не умеет работать с модулями.
2. Вы переобъявляете существующую функцию. *Стоит назвать функцию по-другому.*
3. Это предупреждение оптимизации. Оно говорит, что вы не использовали переменную `i`.